# xpath - find specific image in a div within a div, in url

Tags: html, xpath

I am trying to get the image src url from a autotrader but for some reason i get the error:

**`Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttribute() on a non-object`**

My code:

```
$url = 'http://www.autotrader.ca/a/Audi/A4/BURNABY/British+Columbia/19_8423269_/?ursrc=pl&urp=1&urm=8&showcpo=ShowCPO';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true); 
$request = $dom->loadHTMLFile($url);
$DOMxpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$image = $DOMxpath->query("//div[@class='fgIDiv']//div/img");
echo $image->item(0)->getAttribute('src');
```

I can get the any other element with text but i'm having trouble with the images, especially when they have not id or class.

Please help me out!

Comment: I don't know if you're working with the HTML after Javascript has done it's work or not, but `div[@class='fgIDiv']` is not present in the HTML in my browser when viewing source. But you have the image URLs in a Javascript variable called `photoxml`, inside a small XML document with `img` elements

Comment: I am using html, php, css only. If you open the developers tool (F12), and click on the image, it will show you that it's inside div[@class='fgIDiv']

Comment: In the developers tools, you're seeing HTML *after* Javascript has been interpreted, this is not something `loadHTMLFile` can do.

Comment: is there a way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: I don't think you can do this with XPath from the downloaded HTML. You could use something like Selenium to work on the "Javascript rendered" document or work on parsing the Javascript snippet embedded in the page to parse the XML and get image links (where you could use XPath in fact).

Comment: I managed to do it with regex for other wesbites just cannot do it on this specific one. Using xpath i can get all the text though no issues..

Comment: Indeed, regex is another option: look for the `<script>` element which contains `var photoxml =` and then extract the rest of the line. This is the XML document string that contains the image links.